# android program doesn t work in mobile but it works correctly in tablet and emulator

Tags: android, sqlite, mobile, emulation

I wrote a program in eclipse using SQLite.

When I run it,it works correctly in emulator(API 7) and also works correctly when i run it on tablet with android version 2.2.

But when i try to run it in mobile with android version 2.3,it doesn't work and give me this error:

error compiling `:String query = "SELECT Cart_ID from Tbl order by Cart_ID DESC limit 1"`

my main code:

```
public void insertQuote(String Quote,int Price1,int Count1,int GoodIDEnter ) 
{
              String query = "SELECT Cart_ID from Tbl_Cart order by Cart_ID DESC limit 1";
              Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
               if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) 
               {
                   goodid = c.getLong(0); 

               }
}
```

What should i do?

Comment: sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.example.test/databases/NFC.sqlite", &handle, 2, NULL) failed

Comment: "failed"? Show the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

Add/Modify this in your manifest file.